# Doctrine ORM Entity data not being persisted to the database upon flush()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, persistence

I'm updating the entity User which has a OneToMany bidirectional relationship with Profiles and a OneToOne relationship with Contact. When I update (flush) the User entity, everything is updated apart from the user column on tblProfile even though the entity returned is correct.

I've tried updating the User/Profile relationship from both sides, see the final 2 lines of the code snippet. Both methods return the correct final entities, however the table tblProfile isn't updated.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I can provide more parts of the code also!

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Domain\Repository\ProfileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="tblProfile")
 */
class ProfileEntity
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserEntity", inversedBy="profiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="PfUScId", referencedColumnName="UScId")
     */
    private ?UserEntity $user = null;

        /**
     * @return UserEntity|null
     */
    public function getUser(): ?UserEntity
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserEntity|null $user
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUser(?UserEntity $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Domain\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="tblUser")
 */
class UserEntity
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProfileEntity", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private Collection $profiles;

     /**
     * @param array $profiles
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setProfiles(array $profiles): self
    {
        $this->profiles = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $this->profiles->add($profile);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getProfiles(): Collection
    {
        return $this->profiles;
    }
}

class UserService
{
    public function updateUser(
        int $legacyUserId,
        string $email,
    ): UserEntity {
      $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['legacyUserId' => $legacyUserId]); 
      $profiles = $user->getProfiles();


      $existingContact = $this->checkContact($user, $email);
      $Contact = $existingContact
          ? $existingContact :
          $this->contactService->createContact($email);

      $user->setContact($contact)->setId($contact->getId());

      $updatedProfiles = [];
      foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
        $updatedProfiles[] = $profile->setContact($contact)->setUser($user);
      }
      $user->setProfiles($updatedProfiles);

      $user = $this->userRepository->updateUser($user);

      foreach($updatedProfiles as $profile) {
        $this->profileService->changeUser($profile, $user);
      }


      return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would like to update profiles witch are already assigned to user, the profile has the id of user so you don't have to say `$user->setProfiles($updatedProfiles);` because you will update just the profiles witch already exist.

try this :

```
  // delete this line $updatedProfiles = []; 
  foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
   // $updatedProfiles[] = to be deleted
    $profile->setContact($contact)->setUser($user);
  }
  // delete this lline $user->setProfiles($updatedProfiles);
```